# Excel Subtract months from specified date?

Tags: excel, datediff

How will i subtract months from specified date using `datediff` function?

for example:

```
17/10/2013 -(3 months) = 17/07/2013?
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is in A1, this will give you the date 3 months earlier:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-3,DAY(A1))
```

`Date` creates a date given the year, month, and day provided. It will handle negatives correctly (so it will work in February, adjusting the year as needed.)

`Datedif` returns the difference between two given dates -- the reverse of what you're looking for.
`Datediff` is a function in MS SQL and Access.